# Power BI - Calculating Sum Between 2 Times with DAX

Tags: datetime, powerbi, dax

I have half-hourly consumption data and I need to calculate the sum of consumption that takes place between 2:30 AM and 5:00 AM.

I have achieved this in Excel with a SUMIF statement. How do I do this with DAX, though?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you share a sample dataset?

Comment: Hello, did my answer solve your issue? If so would you mind accepting it as the solution and upvoting it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a table with columns similar to those in the sample table below, I've included the DAX to calculate the sum of consumption between the times given. This also assumes that you want to calculate this sum for ALL days between 2:30 AM and 5:00 AM.

**Sample Table (Table)**

| id | consumption | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 2022-05-28 02:00 |
| 2 | 4 | 2022-05-28 02:30 |
| 3 | 5 | 2022-05-28 03:00 |
| 4 | 5 | 2022-05-28 03:30 |
| 5 | 6 | 2022-05-28 04:00 |
| 6 | 6 | 2022-05-28 04:30 |
| 7 | 5 | 2022-05-28 05:00 |
| 8 | 5 | 2022-05-28 05:30 |

**Solution Measure**

```
Consumption Sum = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Table'[consumption]), 
        TIME(
            HOUR('Table'[timestamp]), 
            MINUTE('Table'[timestamp]), 
            SECOND('Table'[timestamp])
        ) >= TIMEVALUE("02:30:00"), 
        TIME(
            HOUR('Table'[timestamp]), 
            MINUTE('Table'[timestamp]), 
            SECOND('Table'[timestamp])
        ) <= TIMEVALUE("05:00:00")
    )
```

**Sample Result**

[image: Measure Result]

A similar result could be achieved using the [SUMX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/sumx-function-dax) function if that's more intuitive for you.